# How do I add a tuning potentiometer to modify the incoming control voltage of an XR8038?

Tags: analog, synthesizer, vco

I have been working on designing an analog synth and have decided to use an [XR8038](http://k1.dyndns.org/Develop/Hardware/Infomix/ICs%20analog,%20low%20integration/XR-8038A%20Waveform%20Generator%200.001-200kHz.pdf) as my VCO. If I wanted to add a tuning modifier would this configuration I made be okay?

[image]

P.S. Would I need to attach a LFO to this VCO to get it working? If so how should I approach it?

Comment: FWIW, to make this work (without regard to its appropriateness), connect pin 2 of R4 to ground and connect pin 3 of R4 to FM_BIAS. That gives you a voltage divider for the bias supply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are aware (I presume) that this will not make a suitable VCO for an analogue synth (without jumping thru several hoops of complication). An analogue synth VCO **MUST** have this: -

Any single octave change in frequency comes about when the input voltage changes the same amount as for any other octave change.

Rephrasing, if 1V produces 100Hz and 2V produces 200Hz then 3V should produce 400Hz and 4V should produce 800Hz. It's called a log-VCO in the industry and it's very important if you want to run VCOs in tandem and it's most noticable when the tandem VCOs are creating a root musical note and (say) a musical fifth. This could be brought about by (say) 1V on one VCO input and 1.5 volts on the other. If you then moved both control voltages up by an amount to create a rising pitch, the relationship musically between the two notes remains the same. You could end up with 3V on input 1 and 3.5V on input 2 - the two notes would still be musically one-fifth apart.

An XR8038 cannot do this without a significant amount of design work in exactly the area you want information on BUT, if you just want to try it out, connect a 1k pot across the supply and attach the wiper to the FM input via a 2k2 and see how it works out. This is called a linear VCO.

Comment: What would you recommend I use instead?

Comment: It's a great oscillator - it has a nearly 10 octave sweep range (1 to 1000x freq) from the voltage (FM) input so it's half there but converts volts to frequency linearly. You need to have a circuit between your control voltage and the input of the 8038 that maps a linear input voltage range to a range that gives you 1v per octave on the output. I'd strongly consider using a small MCU with a 16bit ADC and a 16bit DAC - the MCU does the conversion from one realm to the other. The ADC reads the pot and the DAC writes the "modified" control voltage to the 8038.

Comment: I called it a log-vco but most hits on google come from the phrase "exponential vco". Here's a circuit and some ideas: http://www.birthofasynth.com/Thomas_Henry/Pages/VCO-1.html#Design_Analysis:_The_Exponential_Converter. Here are some more: http://www5b.biglobe.ne.jp/~houshu/synth/

Comment: I'd also add (having had a go at building synths years ago) that it's impossible to overstate just how accurate this has to be if you want to use it for anything musical.